# git push heroku master Building dependencies error

Tags: heroku, git-push, heroku-toolbelt

i am using heroku and my server is written in Node JS.
while trying
    git push heroku master

I am am getting the following Error

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  4.1.2
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Downloading and installing node 4.1.2...
remote:        Using default npm version: 2.14.4
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_a220092b4f1662f47548204bbda7d972/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_a220092b4f1662f47548204bbda7d972/.heroku/
node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_a220092b4f1662f47548204bbda7d972/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v4.1.2
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! version not found: e@2.7.1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
remote:        npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_a220092b4f1662f47548204bbda7d972/npm-debug.log
```

my package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "myServerTry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "InfoBroker application",
    "engines": {
    "node": "4.1.2"
  },

  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "connect": "^3.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-csv": "^0.6.0",
    "foobar": "^1.1.0",
    "e": "^0.0.4",
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "qs": "^6.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

In my local files, everything is working just fine.
I also checked the version of the dependencies and it is all right.
any ideas?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.